# How do I put more than one label into a frame using tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to put a label underneath another label on a frame in tkinter but I either get one label printing on top of the other or I seem to get my frame doubled up underneath itself. How do I fix this problem?

This is the code I am using:

```
class teachingContent(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(teachingContent, self).__init__()
        self.nextLabel = None
        self.nextLabelText = StringVar()
        self.nextLabelText.set("Next window")

        self.tutorTitleFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=16, weight='bold')
        self.tutorContentFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight='normal')
        self.tutorCodeFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='normal')
        self.tutorButtonFont = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')
        self.title_height = 40


        self.firstProgram_title_frame = ttk.Frame()
        self.firstProgram_frame = ttk.Frame()





    def nextButtonPressed(self):
        pass



    def prevButtonPressed(self):
        pass


    def formSize(self):

        self.configure(bg = 'black') # Sets the colour of the gui screen to black
        self.geometry("650x450+200+200") # Sets the size of the gui
        self.title("Python Tutor")


        self.nbutton = Button(text = "Next", command = self.nextButtonPressed, bg = 'grey25', activebackground = 'gray19',
                              activeforeground = 'DodgerBlue1', fg = 'royal blue', width = 8, font = self.tutorButtonFont).place(x=561,y=418)

        self.pbutton = Button(text = "Previous", command = self.prevButtonPressed, bg = 'grey25', activebackground = 'gray19',
                              activeforeground = 'DodgerBlue1', fg = 'royal blue', width = 8, font = self.tutorButtonFont).place(x=0,y=418)


        self.firstProgram_title_frame.configure(height=self.title_height)
        self.firstProgram_title_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
        self.firstProgram_title_frame.grid(column=0, 0, padx=33,
                                    pady=50, sticky=(W, N, E))

        self.firstProgram_frame.configure()
        self.firstProgram_frame['borderwidth'] = 2
        self.firstProgram_frame['relief'] = 'sunken'
        self.firstProgram_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=33, pady=50, sticky=(W, N, E))




    def firstProgram(self):
        self.formSize()
        self.firstProgramTitleLabel = Label(self.firstProgram_title_frame, text = "A First Program", font=self.tutorTitleFont)
        self.firstProgramTitleLabel.pack()
        self.firstProgramLabel = Label(self.firstProgram_frame, text = "This program reads in two numbers, adds them together and then prints out the result",
                                    font = self.tutorContentFont, wraplength = 500, width = 35, height = 14)

        self.firstProgramLabel.grid(column=self.0, row=0, ipadx = 85, pady = 11, padx = 11, sticky=(N))
        self.firstProgram = Label(self.firstProgram_frame, text = "# This program works out the result by adding 2 numbers\n# Rob Miles November 2012\n\n# Read the numbers\
                                  \nfirstString = input ('Enter the first number: ')\nfirstNumber = int(firstString)\
                                  \nsecondString = input ('Enter the second number: ')\nsecondNumber = int(secondString)\n\n# work out the sum\
                                  \nresult = firstNumber + secondNumber\n\n# Display the result\nprint ('The result is: ', result)",
                                    font = self.tutorCodeFont, wraplength = 500, width = 35, height = 14, justify = LEFT)

        self.firstProgram.grid(column=self.0, row=0, ipadx = 85, pady = 11, padx = 11, sticky=(N))



tc = teachingContent()
tc.firstProgram()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time put some effort in posting a working code here, right?

My traceback log to make your code running:

```
  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 68
    self.firstProgramLabel.grid(column=self.0, row=0, ipadx = 85, pady = 11, padx = 11, sticky=(N))
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 75
    self.firstProgram.grid(column=self.0, row=0, ipadx = 85, pady = 11, padx = 11, sticky=(N))
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 50
    self.firstProgram_title_frame.grid(column=0, 0, padx=33,
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 3, in <module>
    class teachingContent(Tk):
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 79, in <module>
    tc = teachingContent()
  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.tutorTitleFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=16, weight='bold')
NameError: name 'font' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 80, in <module>
    tc = teachingContent()
  File "tkinterlabel.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.firstProgram_title_frame = ttk.Frame()
NameError: name 'ttk' is not defined
```

Mistakes you've made:

- submitted a wrong code
- you simply messed up grid rows and columns
- you mixed grid and pack layout managers
- height in Label is measured in rows not pixels

Some of the corrections:

```
self.firstProgram_title_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=33, pady=5, sticky='n')
self.firstProgram_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=33, sticky='n')
self.firstProgramTitleLabel.grid(column=0, row=0)
self.firstProgramLabel = Label(self.firstProgram_frame, text = "blabla", font = self.tutorContentFont, wraplength = 500, width = 35)
self.firstProgram.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='n', ipadx = 85)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, and your code doesn't run, so it's hard to give a definitive answer. There are at least three ways to put one label on top of another -- pack, grid and place.

I am guessing you're concerned about `self.firstProgramLabel` and `self.firstProgram`. In both cases you are putting them in the same row, so they will be on top of each other unless you put them in different columns. In one, you try putting it in `self.0`, which I'm guessing is a typo and you are intending column 0 (zero). The second one you don't specify a column, so it will default to zero. Thus, both widgets are going in row 0, column 0. If you don't want them on top of each other, either change the row or change the column.

When using `grid`, it's best to always explicitly designate the row and column.